# Unable to resolve JRE: jdk1.8.0_121 (Standard VM) in dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm using hibernate, eclipse, MySql to build dynamic web project. Actually, the project runs without any problem. But in the build path, it shows as  `Unable to resolve JRE: jdk1.8.0_121 (Standard VM)` how to I resolve this?

[image: Unable to resolve JRE: jdk1.8.0_121 (Standard VM)]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Select "JRE System Library[...] (unbound)" then click on "Edit..." button and check if the path of your jdk exists

Comment: So far I have checked the jdk in alternate jdk. Now I resolved it by giving workspace jdk. Thank you for reminding me to check the build path.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,

In `Edit Configuration and Launch window` (right click on build.xml > run as > Ant build...), I was getting error message:

```
[JRE]: Unable to resolve JRE: jre1.8.0_171 (Standard VM)
```

I solved it by setting the Runtime JRE to `Run in the same JRE as the workspace`, in same dialog as above but in the JRE tab.

[Edit Configuration and Launch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMBC1.png)